# How do I compare strings between sheets and then add the current date if the value is true

Tags: excel, vba

I am a novice user looking for some guidance. How would I go about comparing strings between two excel sheets? I need to take names from sheet one, Column B and I, check where the names exist in sheet two, column A, then add the current date next to the the correct name, Column B, in sheet 2. I would like this to be done daily via macro or script. The name data in sheet 1 would be changing daily.

I am not sure how to tackle this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [start here](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula (place in the second sheet in cell B2): IF(VLOOKUP(A2;sheet2!A:A;1;false)=A2;TODAY();"")

Replace the sheet name, replace A2 with the cell you are searching for, replace A:A with the range (or single cell) you are searching for, and populate the formula into other cells down below the first cell. You can record a simple macro around this (Google for "recording a macro in excel 2003".. or whatever version of excel you are using), then you can escape the need of writing a script.